# Flatlist (Conversation screen) in chat application with large data slow down the other components

Tags: react-native

I'm developing a chat application with react native but the Flatlist  with large data  slow down the other components like emoji or textinput can someone elp me ?

```
  <FlatList
   ref={ref => this.chatFlatList = ref}
   data={this.state.messages1}
   showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}

   inverted
   renderItem={this.renderChatList}
   keyExtractor={(_,index) => index.toString()}
   ListFooterComponent={() =>  <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" /> }
   windowSize={10000}
   />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
windowSize={10000)
```

means that the component will render the visible screen area plus (up to) 4999 screens above and 4999 below the viewport.

> Reducing this number will reduce memory consumption and may improve
> performance, but will increase the chance that fast scrolling may
> reveal momentary blank areas of unrendered content.
>
> (was taken from the 'VirtualizedList" [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.44/virtualizedlist#windowsize))

Try changing the window size (to 11 for example) and see if helps.

Another thing you can do is to add

```
removeClippedSubviews={true}
```

which is

> a native optimization that removes clipped subviews (those outside the
> parent) from the view hierarchy to offload work from the native
> rendering system